# Prime number and Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let  $p$ be a prime number such that  $p^2+12$ has exactly $5$ divisors.  What is the maximum value of $p$ ?

I came across this question in a Math Olympiad Competition and had no idea how to solve it

Comment: A number with an odd number of divisors must be square.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that a number that has 5 divisors must be in the form of $q^{4}$ for some prime $q$. So we get:

$q^{4}=p^{2}+12 \implies (q^{2}-p)(q^{2}+p)=12$

Then do some casework on it.

Comment: The answer I have got is 2(maximum value of P). I think I am right ?

Comment: @MohammadMizanurRahaman: yes, $p=q=2$

Answer (score 0):

Using @LordSharktheUnknown's hint that a number with an odd number of divisors must be square

we are then looking for cases where $p^2+12=a^2$ i.e. $a^2-p^2 = 12$

Since $7^2-6^2=13$, this tells you $a^2-p^2 \gt 12$ for $a \ge 7$ and $p \lt a$

so here we must have  $a \lt 7$ and thus prime $p \in \{2,3,5\}$.  Considering these:

- $2^2+12=16=4^2$ so $p=2$ is indeed a possibility
- $3^2+12=21$, not a square, so $p=3$ is not a possibility
- $5^2+12=37$, not a square, so $p=5$ is not a possibility